# SUMIF with date range for specific column

Tags: filter, google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I've been trying to find an answer for this, but haven't succeeded - I need to sum a column for a specified date range, as long as my rowname matches the reference sheet's column name.

i.e

**Reference_Sheet**

```
Date     John  Matt
07/01/19 1     2
07/02/19 1     2
07/03/19 2     1
07/04/19 1     1
07/05/19 3     3
07/06/19 1     2
07/07/19 1     1
07/08/19 5     9
07/09/19 9     2
```

**Sheet1**

```
     A     B     

  1        07/01
  2        07/07
  3        Week1 
  4  John  10
  5  Matt  12
```

Have to work in google sheets, and I tried using `SUMPRODUCT` which told me I can't multiply texts and I tried `SUMIFS` which let me know I can't have different array arguments - failed efforts were similar to below,

```
=SUMIFS('Reference_Sheet'!B2:AO1000,'Reference_Sheet'!A1:AO1,"=A4",'Reference_Sheet'!A2:A1000,">=B1",'Reference_Sheet'!A2:A1000,"<=B2")
```

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Reference_Sheet'!$A$2:$AO$1000)*('Reference_Sheet'!$A$2:$A$1000>=B$1)*('Reference_Sheet'!$A$2:$A$1000<=B$2)*('Reference_Sheet'!$A$1:$AO$1=$A4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
=sumifs(indirect("Reference_Sheet!"&address(2,match(A4,Reference_Sheet!A$1:AO$1,0))&":"&address(100,match(A4,Reference_Sheet!A$1:AO$1,0))),Reference_Sheet!A$2:A$100,">="&B$1,Reference_Sheet!A$2:A$100,"<="&B$2)
```

But you'll need to specify how many rows down you need it to go. In my formula, it looks down till 100 rows.

To change the number of rows, you need to change the number in three places:

1. &address(`100`
2. Reference_Sheet!A$2:A$`100`," ... in two places

---

To briefly explain what is going on:

- look for the person's name in row 1 using `match`
- Use `address` and `indirect` to build the address of cells to add
- and then `sumIfs()` based on dates.

Answer (score 0):

alternative:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY($A:$D, 
 "where A >= date '"&TEXT(F$1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and A <= date '"&TEXT(F$2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 1)), 
 "where Col1 = '"&$E4&"'", 0))
```

[image: 0]